# Get the current class from HTML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I'm trying to get a "check all" checkbox working and I can't seem to find a way.
Edit: the issue is that in my case; the class names are all "checkButtonLot (current lot number)" as they're generated through a "for" loop in the twig. What I don't get is how to pass that current lot number as a variable to the Js; so that when I click on the 1st lot number checkbox; the 1st lot number sub-products are all checked; but the rest of the lot numbers are not.

Here's the Twig for the checkbox that should check the rest:

```js
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input id="checkButtonLot{{ currentProduct.lotNumber }}" type="checkbox"
        class="custom-control-input js-checkBoxLot{{ currentProduct.lotNumber }} js-checkable"
        name="checkButtonLot{{ currentProduct.lotNumber }}" value="{{ currentProduct.lotNumber }}">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="checkButtonLot{{ currentProduct.lotNumber }}"></label>
</div>
```

Here's the twig for the other checkboxes:

```js
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input id="checkButtonLotsub_product{{ sub_product.rankId }}_{{currentProduct.lotNumber}}" type="checkbox"
        class="custom-control-input js-checkBoxLotsub_product{{ sub_product.rankId }}_{{currentProduct.lotNumber}} js-checkable"
        name="checkButtonLotsub_product{{ sub_product.rankId }}_{{currentProduct.lotNumber}}"
        value="{{ sub_product.id }}_{{ sub_product.rankId }}_{{currentProduct.lotNumber}}">
    <label class="custom-control-label"
        for="checkButtonLotsub_product{{ sub_product.rankId}}_{{currentProduct.lotNumber}}"></label>
</div>
```

Here's the Js script that's supposed to make it work:

```js
var checkBoxSelectAllOneLot = Array.prototype.slice.call(
    document.getElementsByClassName(classCheckboxesLots)
);
addEventAllOneLot(checkBoxSelectAllOneLot);

function addEventAllOneLot(checkboxAll) {
    var checkboxAll = checkBoxSelectAllOneLot;
    checkboxAll.map(function (btnElement) {
        console.log(btnElement);
        btnElement.addEventListener("click", selectAllOneLot);
    });
}

function selectAllOneLot() {
var separator = "_";
    var lotNumber = this.value.split([separator[1]]);
    var checkboxAllOneLot = Array.prototype.slice.call(
        document.getElementsByClassName(classCheckboxesLotWafer)
    );
    console.log(checkboxAllOneLot);

    if (this.checked == true) {
        checkboxAllOneLot.map(function (checkbox) {
            checkbox.checked = true;
            checkbox.classList.toggle("checked");
        });
    } else {
        checkboxAllOneLot.map(function (checkbox) {
            checkbox.checked = false;
        });
    }

    deselectButtonAll();
}
```

EDITED: the display language isn't HTML its indeed Twig.
Any one would have any insight on this, I'd appreciate greatly.
Have a good one

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? `checkButtonLot{{ currentProduct.lotNumber }}` does not look like valid  HTML markup, but rather like a Twig template

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Pleasse do not post server template code if the question is about client side issues

Comment: There seems to be some JS missing. What is `this`? Why use `slice` on the element collection. What is `[separator[1]]`? And so on…

Comment: @NicoHaase what's not working is when I click on "checkButtonLot"; the other checkboxes don't get checked. You're right, it's indeed twig, not html.

Comment: For now I've tried fiddling with the Js & class names with no luck. From what I can read in my code; it should be working; yet i have no errors in my console no warnings etc. The issue seems to come from either the checkboxSelectAllOneLot; as it doesn't seem to find the class "checkbuttonLot" followed by the current lot number; or the function selectAllOneLot since putting alerts in it does'nt make them appear on screen when the script reaches them.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty convoluted, so I'm not going to weed through it (no offense), but here's a very simple method I'm sure you can adapt for your situation:

```js
document.getElementById("check-all").addEventListener('change', changeHandler)

function changeHandler(event) {
    for (const checkbox of document.querySelectorAll('.group')) {
        checkbox.checked = event.target.checked
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check-all"> <label for="check-all">check all</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="group">
<input type="checkbox" class="group">
<input type="checkbox" class="group">
<input type="checkbox" class="group">
```

Comment: no offense taken, it's not my code and I agree its pretty convoluted (I don't have the contact for the previous dev on it; so I can't even reach him to ask about it); I'll try with the snippet you gave thanks !